# multiple commands with . (dot) in vim

Tags: vim

How can I record multiple actions to later be performed with a single dot?

example arrange the line bellow to the default indent:
J

if I now go down one line and press dot it only performs the

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you want to bring the `.(dot)` repeat features on your own plugin/functions, you can check this plugin: https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat

Another possibility for repeating multiple operations/commands is defining or recording a macro, and replay it. Read `:h q` for details.

For your example, you can record:

```
qqJjq
```

Then `@q` to replay, also once you have replayed it, you can press `@@` to replay previous macro.